# Uniswap/pancake fork

Tags: ethereum, solidity, binance-smart-chain, uniswap

I've a smart contract that use swapTokenForTokens to swap from wbnb, that are inside the contract, to the token. I happened to swap on some honeypots and have never been able to sell them. I have read about some forks of uniswap that allow you to bypass honeypots and swap as long as the tokens are in the contract. In theory my contract does this but it doesn't work. Can you give me some information about it?

Answer (score 0):

Each scam token will have it's own methods of blocking a token... Tokens that block the approval can be circumvented, but those are rare these days... Each and every token would need to be checked to see why it's failing